# Web.xml maping servlet in IntelliJ not working

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

i'm new to JEE i have:

- JAVA 8 and 14
- IntelliJ Ultimate
- Tomcat 6

When i create a Servlet and JSP file the web.xml is not updating and mapping the new files

i only get this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

Comment: I know it might be confusing but Tomcat is up to version 10.  Tomcat 6 hasn't been supported in about 5 years.  Additionally, you no longer have to have anything in `web.xml` - it is optional.  How old is the tutorial you're following?

Comment: How do you create a servlet in IntelliJ IDEA?